# Can a Force-user split an atom with the Force?

Tags: star-wars

I always wondered if this was possible or has been done in canon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT that i'm aware of in canon based on much googling/wookipediaing.

But it happened in fanon (*which I personally don't accept as valid SW info but may be worth throwing into the answer in case OP does*).

From http://swfanon.wikia.com/wiki/Fission:

> Force Fission was the ability to split an object using the Force. An adept in the Force **could split something as small as an atom**, thereby creating large amounts of energy and destructive power. The power was the exact opposite of Force Fusion, and it was less effective in water.

Answer (score 6):

[Abeloth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abeloth) could not do it and she(it) was probably the strongest force using being in existance.

She was able to manipulate matter that existed already in ways beyond even the celestials but she had to have the matter to manipulate.

She was not able to create explosions of her own but she was able to rip bedrock from beneath the Galactic Senate tower that would eventually cause it to collapse but was not able to just cause a nuclear explosion to destroy it.  Concievably if she could have done so she could have done the reverse and stopped it.  She was not able to do that either when she was taken out by an overloaded fusion generator on the moon of Mykryr(I believe that was the system)

Comment: What is the source for this? I can't say I'm familiar with the character

Comment: @GabeWillard - Fate of the Jedi Series.  I believe the specific instance I mentioned was from [Conviction](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conviction), though Abeloth is explored through out the series.