# Can a Force User shape reality?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Not sure how much [Can a Force-user split an atom with the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22014/can-a-force-user-split-an-atom-with-the-force) answers my question, maybe only partially.

I don't really mean creating matter out of thin air, but inducing chemical reactions? If you can move stuff with the Force, and if you can effect the biochemical state of an organic's mind to think different things, then, in theory, is a Force user capable of synthesizing water from hydrogen and oxygen by just smashing them together hard enough?

If I recall correctly, the Star Forge used the dark side to build a great manner of things, so I would imagine the natural Force, theoretically being greater than the full power of the dark side, would be capable of similar stuff.

Not just at the atomic, but also at a larger scale: Given enough effort, time and unlimited access to the Force, can a Force user theoretically construct a star system out of a nebula?

Can Force users play god? Or is it

> That's not how the Force works!

**Edit**: Let's not forget lightsaber crystals can be synthesized. Although I don't know the specifics, it does seem to be an example affirming my question.

Comment: Disney Canon or Legends? Because Sith Alchemy in Legends does some *pretty* weird stuff. (Funnily enough, synthesizing your own crystal was a thing the Sith since Darth Bane had to do since they - at least according to *Coruscant Nights II: Street of Shadows* (which I just finished, therefore remembered that tidbit) - didn't have access to Ilum or Adega.) Also in Legends, when Mon Mothma gets poisoned in the Jedi Academy Trilogy Cilghal goes rather deep into things to seperate good cells from poison, but that is of course still a long way from altering reality at the quantum level...

Comment: I think the assumption that the Jedi mind trick affects "the biochemical state of an organic's mind" is not necessarily founded in the fiction. The often mystical descriptions of the Force and its effects suggest that the minds of organic beings may be a metaphysical phenomenon that cannot be reduced to chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Well... This is pretty broad!

***NOTE*** - The following examples come from what is now known as *Legends* and thus has been removed as Canon. These are simply famous examples from *Legends* to showcase how it has been done in the past.

In terms of playing God, in legends, [Vitiate](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Valkorion) was able to make himself immortal, by absorbing the life force of an entire planets worth of living things. He was able to change the laws around death and ageing through the use of the dark side.

[Palpatine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) was able to construct wormholes in the middle of space to destroy entire fleets. Our present understanding of wormholes are murky, but there is a significant bending of the fabric of space-time.

[Nihilus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Nihilus) was able to absorb energy into himself at huge rates, while also encasing his consciousness inside an inanimate object.

So it seems perfectly reasonable to say that a Force user (commonly darksided) with enough skill was able to perform feats that seem to bend the rules of reality.

As for inducing chemical reactions, there is a force power called [Art of the Small](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Art_of_the_Small) that allowed a practitioner to project a microscopic version of themselves and rearrange molecules. This power was used by [Vergere](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vergere) so that she could literally sweat toxins.

[Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis) managed to create life through direct manipulation of midichlorians. Midichlorians are microscopic life forms and thus, he was causing microscopic chemical reactions.

Answer (score 1):

The Star Forge did indeed built spaceships, weapons and droids (among other things), very quickly with use of the Dark Side. However, it is not clear whether the Dark Side actually materialized its creations, or simply let let the factory utilize the Force to speed up it's existing production. I could be wrong, feel free to correct me if that is the case.

From the movies, however, we know that you through the Force can manipulate the beloved midi-chlorians to create life, seemingly from nothing. **So in that sense, yes, you could use the Force to shape reality**.

In theory (at least in my opinion) I think that Force users could create water from oxygen and hydrogen, but I would imagine that it would be pretty challenging and not really solve any problems.

Comment: "not really solve any problems" a certain Jedi Master from a moisture farm on Tatooine would beg to differ...

Comment: Just FYI, the Rakata who created the Star Forge powered their civilization with the dark side, quite literally as electricity. It probably goes beyond that. When the Rakata suddenly lost access to the dark side, they couldn't operate the Forge and thus lost their empire. The Forge wasn't destroyed for millennia, however - if the dark side was just "electricity" to the Forge, a simple makeover could turn it into an orbital shipyard powered by more conventional methods. But it didn't.

Comment: By stating that I don't think it would solve any problem I meant that It would require a huge effort, and I don't think even a Jedi Master could mass-produce water. Thus I think it would be extremely inefficient, but I'm just speculating.

Comment: If the Star Forge was built with the intention that everything would be powered by the Force, I don't think a "simple makeover" would be sufficient to change how it is powered. Image a Jet plane running out of fuel, you couldn't just make a few simple changes to get it to run on electricity, for a myriad of reasons. Now apply that thinking to something as large as a space station that run on something as complicated as the Force.

Comment: The Rakata were natural Force sensitives. They used the Force like we used electricity, but also like how the Jedi and Sith use the Force, and then more. That's all I know about their civilisation as a whole. Exactly how much of that applies to the Star Forge I do not know.